# Wordpress, create json file when a term is updated/deleted/created

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have to create a json file when a term is created/updated/deleted from a taxonomy "product_cat", below i attempt to register a simple json file but without success :

```
add_action( 'create_term',  'wpse_create_term', 10, 3 );
add_action( 'created_term', 'wpse_created_term', 10, 3 );
add_action( 'edited_term',  'wpse_edited_term', 10, 3 );
add_action( 'delete_term',  'wpse_delete_term', 10, 5 );

function wpse_create_term(){
    createJsonFile();
}

function wpse_created_term(){
    createJsonFile();
}

function wpse_edited_term(){
    createJsonFile();
}

function wpse_delete_term(){
    createJsonFile();
}

function createJsonFile(){

    echo "begin write to json file to " . dirname(__FILE__);
    $data = array("a","b","c","d");
    //format the data
    $formattedData = json_encode($data);
    //set the filename
    $filename = 'members.json';
    //open or create the file
    $handle = fopen($filename,'w+');
    //write the data into the file
    fwrite($handle,$formattedData);
    //close the file
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Firstly, why those hooks never fired ( the echo is not printed when updating a term ) ? and how should i specify destination folder for the final json file?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: json file is creating in the path `wp-admin`

Comment: You're right, thank you.

Comment: do want to specify the folder path?

Answer (score 1):

You cant echo something from the function file you might want to use the debug.log for it
Secondly you need to specify a location where to create the json file